# Parse verification emails not sent consistently

Tags: parse-platform

I have been using parse as backend for our android and iOS applications.To verify the users we are using parse verification flow.
Most of the times we do receive emails but at times the users are  not receiving the verification emails from parse.

The mails are not in spam as well.

We have enabled verification through parse in settings.

Could you please let us know how can we resolve it.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue, Parse failed to send verification mails to some of mail ids.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did either of you get to the bottom of this?